# Is there a Vs code extension to for CSS that prettify comma separated values as in image?

Tags: css, visual-studio-code

I want the comma separated value not to lie on same line instead lie on different line,

```
.container{
color:red;
backgroud-image:linear-gradient(red,yellow),      
                linear-gradient(grey,purple); //like this 
texta-align:center;
}
```

Example:

[image]

Comment: Try [Prettier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode) it will not work like shown in image but it will prettify your code a lot better.

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: @AbinThaha Vs code

Comment: And you are looking for extensions to do that ?

Comment: yep exactly @AbinThaha

Comment: Prettier or Beautify are the two extensions I use normally. You can edit its config also.

Comment: Idk how to edit the config to  meet my requirement .